# Using Service User to upload files to Google Drive by email address

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am connecting to a service account using [a service account credential](https://www.daimto.com/google-drive-api-with-a-service-account/).

I'm trying to scale this up to be used for multiple users within the same company. All users will have Google accounts managed by this company, and I will have a gsuite service account for the entire company. How can I upload a file to users personal Google Drive based on an email address using a gsuite service account?

Comment: When you say "to users personal Google Drive" do you mean their user-specific account within GSuite, or do you mean their genuine *personal* Drive?

Comment: Their genuine personal drive, under my-drive.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I've been clear. As an example, suppose you're an employee of the Foo company. You would have a Foo Drive account, but you might also have your personal Drive account where you store your family photos etc. That's what I tend to mean by "personal" - non-company-related. I wouldn't want a Foo service account to access that personal Drive account. My guess is that you mean "the individual Drive in the GSuite" - is that right?

Comment: (Please ignore the now-deleted comment with the same content...)

Comment: Ah okay, yes, the service would access that users GSuite drive. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Okay. I don't know the answer, but at least I understand the question better. I'll look into the API definition and see if I can find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `ServiceAccountCredential`, with a `User` property set to the appropriate user.

Assuming you're loading the credentials using `GoogleCredential`, this isn't too hard. For example:

```
GoogleCredential credential = Google.GetApplicationDefault()
    .CreateScoped(...)
    .CreateWithUser("foo@bar.com");
```

If you wanted to use the same original credentials for many different users, you could keep the result of `CreateScoped(...)` around, and just call `CreateWithUser` to create a new user-specific credential for each operation.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will try that. If it works I will mark this as the answer.

Comment: I have run into a TokenResponseException when trying to user `CreateWithUser`, but I believe that this is the answer to my question. Just need to configure the service account properly. Marking as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using Oauth2 you are going to have to have each of the users authentication your application.  This will give you access to their drive account directly.    Now you say you have a master user.  You could just request that these other users share a folder on their Google drive account with the master user then it will have access.  Note you can't share the root directory.

You might want to consider using a service account instead of oauth2 this the users will then have to grant the service account access to their drive account.

Now if this is a gsuite users all of this can be automatically done useing domain wide delegation of the service account.

Comment: The master service account is a gsuite user, so authentication won't be an issue. The problem is that I haven't been able to find documentation that allows me to use an email address to specify which users drive to upload the files to.

Comment: you might want to edit your question then to mention that you are using gsuite and a service account have you consulted this?  https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation

Comment: Edited question accordingly

Comment: the code in that tutorial is for oauth2 its not for service account authentication you should include the correct code

Comment: I have included a link to what I am using to set up the service account authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Here in my work we have the same scenario as you, and to be able to achive this type of integration we created a service account with wide domain delegation enabled for this account.

This way we can use the service account to access users data on their behalf.

But for that, when creating the service account credential, you must impersonate the service account credential passing the user email, this way you'll be able to access user data on their behalf using the service account.

Since you're using C#, I've created a small library that create service account credentials for any type of google api services and for both JSON or P12 credentials.

https://github.com/drodriguesaar/GoogleApiServiceFactory