# Access Api created google spreadsheet on Browser

Tags: c#, google-app-engine

I trying to create a spreadsheet using the google spreadsheets v4. I generated a new server to server credential json on console api. All appears to work, but when I try to access the generated url, I got a screen saying to request permission. The credential was generated from my own service account, associated with my own google account, so I understand that I already have this permission. What could I do to access the generated sheet on browser? Above my code to generate the spreadsheet and the screen I getting.

public class Program
    {
        static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets, SheetsService.Scope.Drive, SheetsService.Scope.DriveFile };
        static string ApplicationName = "Google Sheets API .NET Quickstart";

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppendData();
    }

    public static void AppendData()
    {           
        // the downloaded jsonn file with private key

        var credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(new FileStream(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/ApiKey/api_key.json", FileMode.Open)).CreateScoped(Scopes);

        var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,

        });

        Spreadsheet requestBody = new Spreadsheet()
        {
            Properties = new SpreadsheetProperties()
            {
                Title = "Calculo Projeção",

            },

        };

        SpreadsheetsResource.CreateRequest request = service.Spreadsheets.Create(requestBody);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the GSheet you've created was created using the service account. This means that the service account is the owner of the GSheet.

Depending on what your end goal is, and what type of Google Account you're using you may have some options here.

If you're using a [G Suite account](https://gsuite.google.com/), the solution is relatively simple. It's to use impersonation with the service account. You're then basically using the service account to impersonate a user to perform the actions. If you impersonate your own account while creating the GSheet, the owner will be your own account. The documentation talks about the specifics [here.](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/delegation)

If you're **NOT** using a G Suite account, but a 'normal' Google account, it becomes a bit more tricky. I can think of some options here though:

1. Quick and dirty: Create the GSheet with your personal account first and give the service account access to it.
2. Have the service account create the GSheet and use the API/library to give your personal account access.
3. Create the GSheet not with the service account, but using OAuth and your own credentials. There's several ways to go about this. A good starting point for this would be [here...](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing)

I may have missed one or two here, but you should understand what's actually happening now.

**NOTE:** One very important thing you have to take into account. If you delete the service account, any and all Google Drive items (including Sheets, Docs, Forms, etc) get deleted without any way of getting them back.

Comment: Thanks to the reply. For development I'm using a personal account, but I think in the production environment a G Suite account will be used. This will be a sheet opened with a link on a Web based App. I will check if the G Suite account can be used on development.

Comment: Ok, I got a Gsuit account from my client, but how can I configure to use impersonation for the service account?

Comment: not re-inventing the wheel here, there's an excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49633443/9267296). You basically have to set the User property when creating the GoogleCredential. The user you set there is the user you impersonate.

Comment: one thing you do have to think about is what the end-result needs to be. If you sue impersonation, the owner is going to be the one you've impersonated. You may just want to make the service account the owner of the file, and programatically grant access to the sheet to whomever wants it, but this depends on your actual needs...

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. I will try this tips and report here what I get. Thanks again for taking your time.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the dellay. It works using impersonation. Thanks a Lot!!!